# How does Rust model iterators? Stack or Heap?

Tags: vector, rust, iterator, heap-memory, stack-memory

I know that vectors in Rust are allocated on the heap where the pointer, capacity, and length of the vector are stored on the stack.

Let's say I have the following vector:

```
let vec = vec![1, 2, 3];
```

If I make an iterator from this vector:

```
let vec_iter = vec.iter();
```

How does Rust model this iterator in terms of allocation on the heap vs. stack? Is it the same as the vector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most iterators are stack allocated.

In cases like `Vec::iter()`, they create iterators that have two pointers, one to the end, one to the first element, like so

```rust
use std::marker::PhantomData;

pub struct Iter<'a, T: 'a> {
    ptr: *const T,
    end: *const T,

    _marker: PhantomData<&'a T>,
}
```

Since pointer doesn't convey ownership or lifetime, `PhantomData<&'a T>` tells the compiler this struct holds reference of lifetime `'a` to type `T`

`Iter::next` looks somewhat like this

```rust
impl<'a, T> Iterator for Iter<'a, T> {
    type Item = &'a T;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        unsafe {// pointer dereferencing is only allowed in unsafe
            if self.ptr == self.end {
                None
            } else {
                let old = self.ptr;
                self.ptr = self.ptr.offset(1);
                Some(&*old)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And a new `Iter` is created like so

```
impl<'a, T: 'a> Iter<'a, T> {
    pub fn new(slice: &'a [T]) -> Self {
        assert_ne!(std::mem::size_of::<T>(), 0);    // doesn't handle zero size type
        
        let start = slice.as_ptr();
        Iter {
            ptr: start,
            end: unsafe { start.add(slice.len()) },
            _marker: PhantomData,
        }
    }
}
```

Now we can use it like any other iterators

```rust
let v = vec!['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];

for c in Iter::new(&v) {
    println!("{c}");
}
```

And thanks to `PhantomData`, the compiler can guard us against use after free and other memory issues.

```rust
let iter = {
    let v = vec!['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
    Iter::new(&v)    // error! borrowed value doesn't live long enough
};

for c in iter {
    println!("{c}");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> the pointer, capacity, and length of the vector are stored on the stack

→ not really. They are stored wherever the user wishes, which may be on the stack, in the global data segment, or on the heap:

```
// In the global data segment
static VEC: Vec<()> = Vec::new();

struct Foo {
    v: Vec<()>,
}

fn main() {
    // On the stack
    let v: Vec<()> = Vec::new();
    // On the heap
    let f = Box::new (Foo { v: Vec::new(), });
}
```

And the same goes for iterators. Most of the time they simply hold references to the original data, wherever that may be, and the references themselves are stored inside the iterator `struct` wherever the user puts it.

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled why you introduced `struct Foo` here.

Comment: @SvenMarnach because `Box<Vec<_>>` is very rare, but having a `Vec` as a field in a struct (alongside others) and putting that struct in a box is a lot more common.

Comment: I see. Clippy is actually [linting against this use](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/#box_collection), but I felt it's kind of distracting from the point here.